# docker-compose identical service names in different docker-compose files collision

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are 2 services with 2 `docker-compose.yml` files.
The services are connected via bridge network, so that they can communicate locally.

1. service_1 `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    django:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - "6000:6000"
        networks:
            - shared-local-network
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:6000

networks:
    shared-local-network:
        external: true
```

2. service_2 `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    django:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        networks:
            - shared-local-network
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

networks:
    shared-local-network:
        external: true
```

So those services are in different projects, but their service names are the same: `django`.

But when I am trying to request one service from another, for example send request to service_2 from service_1:

`curl http://django:8000`
It is not reachable.

`netcat -vz django 8000` shows that it is not reachable as well.

I noticed that when sending request from service_1 to `http://django:8000`, it sends request to itself service_1, that's why it cannot find opened 8000 port, because service_1 has 6000 opened port.

Is it possible to resolve without renaming service to a unique one in `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose you have these two paths:

```
/home/service_1/
/home/service_2/
```

And `service_1`'s `docker-compose` is in its same name dir, and `service_2` as well.

When you run `service_1`'s `docker-compose`, the running container name is `service_1_django` and when you run `service_2`'s `docker-compose`, the running container name is `service_2_django`.

So in order to connect these two, you should use either of these two names in each container:

```
service_1_django
service_2_django
```